# Shacl rule to validate data file for mismatched type

Tags: shacl

I have a set of Shacl rules to validate the incoming data files. The issue is when the type of a record in the data file mismatches with the Shacl targetClass, no validation will be done and the Shacl validation engine just reports Success. I got a solution from this website, but it does not work for me. I have posted my Shacl rules and simple data here:

https://s.zazuko.com/b887FZ

The data type "DataInventoryRecord" (data row 20 from the right panel) is correct; when I change the target type, for example changing it to "dataInventoryRecord2", I expect an error, but no error is reported.

I got the idea of recordCountShape from the following post which was answered by Holger Knublauch:

[How to check for a number of class instances with SHACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372064/how-to-check-for-a-number-of-class-instances-with-shacl/62378567#62378567)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The shape definitions look fine to me and also seem to work on the (old) SHACL Playground https://shacl.org/playground/